# How to find an element in an array whose value is maximally distant from the average

Tags: php

Given an array A consisting of four elements:

```
$arr = array(9, 4, -3, -10);
```

The average value of this array is `(9 + 4 + (−3) + (−10)) / 4 = 0`.

The deviation of element `A[2]` is `|(-3) - 0| = |0 - (-3)| = 3`.

The deviation of element `A[3]` is 10. It is an extreme element of array A, since no other element has a deviation greater than 10.

There are no other extreme elements in this array.

I have following solution:

```
<?php
$array = array(9, 4, -3, -10);
$rslt = soln($array);

function soln($A){
    $avg = array_sum($A)/count($A);

    $eE = 0;
    for($i = 0; $i < count($A); $i++){
        if (abs($avg - $A[$i]) > $eE):
            $eE = $i;
        endif;
    }
    if ( (int)$eE > 100000000 ) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return (int)$eE;
    }
}
```

But this solution is not totally correct based on O(N) and O(l)

Answer (score 0):

The maximally distant element from the average would be one of the MAX or MIN elements. So all that you need is to find MAX and MIN elements in the same cycle as calculating array sum. Then you will find the average value based on the array sum and number of elements in the array (just like you do). And then you will check only two elements, MAX and MIN - which of them is maximally distant.

The example of the code:

```
function soln($arr){
  $sum = 0;

  $max = PHP_INT_MIN;
  $min = PHP_INT_MAX;

  foreach($arr as $el){
    if($el > $max){
      $max = $el;
    }

    if($el < $min){
      $min = $el;
    }

    $sum = $sum + $el;
  }

  $avg = $sum/count($arr);

  if(abs($avg - $min) > abs($avg - $max)){
    return $min;
  }else{
    return $max;
  }
}
```

Comment: I need to find the index of an extreme element. If more than one extreme exists then it should return index of any of them

Comment: so just modify this code, store the max and min as an array of max and min, store the corresponded indexes. And your question was "an element" not "elements" :). At least you can use 'array_keys'